# Hausdorff Measure in $R^n and R^m$

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I'm struggling with this exercise at the moment;

Let F ⊂ Rn ⊂ Rm for some integers 0 ≤ n < m.
Let s ≥ 0.
Show that the s-dimensional Hausdorff measure of F is the same whether F is regarded either as a subset
of $R^n$ or of $R^m$

I'm definitely missing something obvious but can't think where to begin.
Can anyone help?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces and $f : X \to Y$ is an isometry, then Hausdorff measure is preserved under $f$.

Comment: Thank you. So it suffices to show that there exists an isometry from $R^n$ to $R^m$?

Comment: The simplest one is $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = (x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,\ldots,0)$.